# Display system logs in a visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

Can I display system logs on a visualforce page like the one below?

[image: Similar to this image]

This image is not from a salesforce system. Just an example.

Thanks.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/464/is-there-a-way-to-access-sfdc-api-log This might be something that you are looking for.